# Easier way to start and stop windows services in Windows XP

Tags: windows-services, windows-xp

I occasionally find myself starting and stopping multiple windows services.  The only tool I'm aware of for stopping and starting windows services is the "Services" program under "Administrative Tools" (%SystemRoot%\system32\services.msc /s).  This program seems to only allow you to manipulate one service at a time, often pausing while it waits for the service to stop.  There is a "Close" button available, but I'd prefer to just select all the services I want to stop or start, and perform a single command on all of them at one time.

Is there an easier way to start and stop multiple windows services for Windows XP?

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. You may be able to get help with this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It possible to start/stop Windows services by using command-line tools such as **net start** and **net stop** and **sc.exe**, but as far as I known none of them allows to operate on more than one service at once.

The easiest solution is to invoke the command-line tool *multiple times* by specifying different service names in a batch file.

Also, note that the reason why there is a delay between issuing a stop command to a Windows Service and the time when the process actually exits, is due to the fact that the **Windows Service Controller** waits up to 30 seconds to allow services to shutdown properly.
If a service doesn't exit by that time, a message will inform you that "*the service didn't respond in a timely fashion*". More details can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174).

Answer (score 13):

Use the "net start" and "net stop" commands in your cmd.exe to start and stop a service:

```
net start "Service name with space"
net stop SerivceNameWithoutSpace
```

Be aware that you will need quotes if the service name has spaces.

Answer (score 4):

You could use powershell.
Something like :
get-service -displayname *SQL* | stop-service
This stops all services with SQL in their display name.
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/stop-service.mspx

Answer (score 3):

What about the [command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564.aspx#BKMK_cmd)?

Answer (score 2):

The net start and net stop commands are where you're going...

Answer (score 1):

Try msconfig (go to the "Run" dialog, type "msconfig"). Choose the "services" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a command/batch script that uses the command-line service controller, `sc.exe`.

Alternatively, you could check out the SysInternals `psservice.exe` command-line tool.